# Add class properties to regular function

Tags: javascript, node.js, function, events

Normally I would create a class and extend it with es6 classes

But this time i got just a regular function that i would like to add the EventEmitter to

```
function hello(){
  return 'world';
}

hello(); // world
```

The function is not a constructor and should not be called with `new`. Now i would also like to have the EventEmitter properties added to this function (much like jquery's `$` where it's both a function and a object)

How would i achieve this?

I was thinking something in terms of:

```
const {EventEmitter} = require('events')

function hello(){
  hello.emit('something', 'called foo')
  return 'world'
}

const myEE = new EventEmitter()
Object.assign(hello, myEE)

hello.on('something', console.log) // called foo
hello() // world
```

but this doesn't work. Do you have any suggestion?
hope there is a better way then doing something like `hello.on = myEE.on` for all of the event's properties

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example doesn't work because all the methods you are looking for (e.g. `on`) exist not in the object itself, but rather in its prototype chain.

To make it work, you can

```
Object.setPrototypeOf(hello, myEE)
```

instead of

```
Object.assign(hello, myEE)
```